# Can Matlab do lazy evaluation?

Tags: matlab, lazy-evaluation

I *think* you can achieve lazy evaluation in Matlab in this way:

```
foo = @() 1+1
% do some other things
bar = foo()
```

As far as I understand the function is not actually evaluated until `foo()` is called. Can it be confirmed if this counts as lazy evaluation or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no better way to achieve this in Matlab, it's [also suggested here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/10/21/delaying-evaluation-of-function-inputs/). Just keep in mind that Matlab won't detect multiple evaluations of the same term. If you do stuff like:

```
foo = @() 1+1
bar=@()foo()*foo()
```

It will evaluate foo two times. Instead the "traditional" way will evaluate it once:

```
foo=1+1
bar=foo+foo
```